# What will be the ElementPath in util:XmlFile when no new line between tags

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer

what will be the `ElementPath` property in `util: XmlFile` tag for `sku` below to change its value to something else if the xml path is like this, where `startup` and `supportedRuntime` tags are in one line:

```
<configuration>
    <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NetFramework,Version=v4.6.2"/></startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

So was able to solve it. When parent and child tag are in same line, here is the `ElementPath=configuration/startup/supportedRuntime[\[]@version='v4.0'[\]]/@sku`  which will get assigned the value and we don't provide the Name tag so this looks like this:

```
<Component Id="UpgradeScenarios" Guid="guid">
                        <Condition><![CDATA[(DIR <> "") AND NOT REMOVE]]></Condition>
                        <CreateFolder/>
                        <util:XmlFile Id="UpdateVersion"
                                      File="id or path"
                                      Action="setValue"
                                      ElementPath="configuration/startup/supportedRuntime[\[]@version='v4.0'[\]]/@sku"
                                      Value="new value"
                                      Sequence="1"/>
                    </Component>
```